# Camunda Embedded Form: Angular 1.2.16 module config function not firing, can't inject factories or services

Tags: angularjs, camunda

I am working Camunda (v7.3.0) for the first time, which uses angular 1.2.16. I am having an issue with the main app module config not firing when the module is loaded. Example:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function () {
   console.log("inside app config");
})
```

When the Camunda form is loaded the above module config function is not fired. Example of index.html

```
<html>
    <script src="/my-warfile-process-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/forms/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="/my-warfile-process-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/forms/main.controller.js"></script>
<body>
    <form ng-app="app" role="form" name="MyCamProcess">

    </form>
</body>
```

When the form is loaded, the app module seems to be only partially bootstrapped if that makes since. angular.module('app') does exist when you run that command in the Chrome console, still the app config is not fired.

The other issues I am having is that, 1) I only define controllers as a separate function ex.

```
(function () {
   angular.module('app').controller("myController", MyController);

   var MyController = function ($scope) {
       /**
        * do controller stuff
        */
   };
})();
```

Not sure if this is angular 1.2.16 thing, I've not work with this version before. 2) I can't inject services or factories in to the controller ex blow

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').controller("myController", MyController);
    angular.module('app').factory("myFactory", MyFactory);

    var MyController = function ($scope, MyFactory) {
        /**
         * do controller stuff
         */
    };

    var MyFactory = function () {
        /**
         * do factory stuff
         */
    };
})();
```

The above give me the error throws the dependency error on the injection into the controller.

Another is that the camForm object, it seems that the only way to access to is to embed a script tag in the form tag and either manually inject the object of throw it on the windows object ex.

```
<form ng-app="app" role="form" name="MyCamProcess">
    <script cam-script type="text/form-script">
        //add to window object
        window.camForm = camForm;

        //inject manually
        inject(function () {
            MyController(camForm);
        })
    </script>
</form>
```

Not sure the inject method works, but it does lol. Any help with this would be most helpful :)

UPDATE:

So, I noticed that the controller and services/factories are being added to the invokedQueue, but not actually being invoked:

[image]

If you noticed in the image above the invokeQueue has 4 elements, 3 being controllers and 1 being a service. If you look at the controller array the length is 0. Not sure why this is happening.......